# How to create draggable View on Map Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to create a draggable view on map like this I have searched on internet but didn't found anything about it. We are using **MapKit** in our application but MapKit doesn't provide this functionality. I want to know that is this a third party library or need to create by ourself but if I create it by myself it will take so much time to create it. Adding Image for reference the App name is **Tap2Map** and **Pix4D**. Please provide some suggestion or is there any library available to create this view on map.

[image]

Comment: You have to create it yourself, it shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: @loremipsum 
 It has lot of functionalities that will take time to create its not just 4 points if I tap between one of those points it create more points can you can check the app and give some suggestions.

Comment: I have no plans on downloading anybodys app. I doubt find a solution out there that meets your needs. You'll have to create it.

Comment: well it's not my app but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following procedure:

- Let the user add an arbitrary or fixed number of location pins (but at least 3 to obtain a valid area). You can let the user do that by tapping on the desired point in the map as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335607/how-to-convert-tap-gesture-to-coordinate-in-a-swiftui-map-view).
- Once there are at least 3 pins, you can render the resulting area by e.g. using [MKOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlay) in combination with a polygon (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_for_appkit_and_uikit/mapkit_overlays/displaying_overlays_on_a_map) for a tutorial)
- I think MapKit's tools should suffice, but alternatively, you could use SwiftUI's `Path` view to create a custom shape (see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/creating-custom-paths-with-swiftui)) by creating a line between every user pin (i.e. go from one pin to the next, plus one from the last to the first to obtain a closed shape). Stroke (`.stroke(..)`) and fill (`.fill(..)`) the shape with reduced opacity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is you should look at implementing this yourself in a custom view. I very much doubt it's part of a library. If it is, and someone knows about it, I hope they let us know, here.

But yes, doing it yourself will take time. But it is mostly doable and doesn't involve very deep SwiftUI knowledge to pull it off - just persistence and good coding. The trickiest part is you would need to be comfortable with some math (basic trigonometry, and perhaps some Matrix algebra, depending on the approach you take) Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are hoping to get here. I can outline a plan, if that helps?

1. Start by considering a control like that outside the context of MapKit. MapKit will make it harder to understand the core of your task (building a control with the desired interaction).
2. First learn about defining a custom [Shape](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape) and understand how you can use [.stroke](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/stroke(linewidth:)) and [.fill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/fill(style:)) on it.
3. Make yourself a custom view that combines some of your custom shapes so that you can have all the parts you need (rectangles, corner circles, arrows, and X). You will probably end up using [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) in here somewhere.
4. Use a [ZStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack) to position your view over another view. Familiarise yourself with API will allow you to position your view as needed. This step is one that you may revisit, as the choices you make will have consequences. It will probably make the most sense to have the View extend to exactly the size of the background view, and do the math to put the parts (the circles, etc) in the right place relative to that. So your view would be as large as the backing view, it only draws itself in the part where it's "supposed to be". I hope that makes sense. But this step is most involved. There's a lot to learn here.
5. Learn how you can uses gesture related methods in SwiftUI to give you the interactions you want. Some of these gesture callbacks will be on your custom view, and some of them will on the view behind it in the ZStack.
6. Once you have all the above working, bring it together with MapKit.

And yes, this will take you a long time, if you don't already have some of the knowledge/experience at hand. But at the end of this journey, you will be a much more capable coder!!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I got interested in trying to create an interactive polygon on a map like the picture you show, where you can
drag the `handles` to new positions. I created a project on github after seeing your question, see:  [MapPoly](https://github.com/workingDog/MapPoly/tree/main)

A bit rough but the code should point to possible ways to achieve what you describe using `SwiftUI` and `MapKit`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I really appreciate that :)