# SwiftUI MapKit get tapped Map location coordinates

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

Is there any way to get the exact coordinates of tapped location (latitude, longitude or CLLocationCoordinate2D) on SwiftUI Map? I have found only [this working method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110673/tapping-an-mkmapview-in-swiftui), however, is there any easier way to do it after the new SwiftUI release/updates?
I need to get the tapped location coordinates to later add annotations/pins on those locations using the coordinates.
[image]

Comment: As far as I know `MapView` does not translate gesture coordinates to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Using the `UIViewRepresentable` approach seems to be the best way.